# Getting cookies set by javascript using PHP curl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies, curl

I'm trying to log into a website, but it seems that the cookies set when logging in, are set using jquery/javascript. Since I am attempting to log in using PHP, the code is unable to pick them up.

I can see the value for the cookie as it would be when set, because it comes in the response to my form submission, but it does not set the cookie because the PHP doesn't seem to interpret the javascript. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: I'm sure there is a way to make this work. Can you share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Of course, PHP does not bundle a JavaScript headless runtime environment. But you can just learn how the code works and send the cookies yourself.

Comment: I found a solution using "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "XXXXXXXXXXX");" It's not the cleanest but it works. Thanks for your responses. :)